# Power BI калькулированный столбец с использованием значения из параметра

Tags: powerbi

Нужно создать столбец, который перемножает значения из параметра и другой столбец. Пробывала так:

```html
SELECTEDVALUE('Parameter'[Parameter value]))*RELATED('tbl_sgm_value'[weight])
```

Выдает пустое поле.